# In IntelliJ how come I can't assign a key mapping to 'Open Recent'

Tags: intellij-idea

If I bring up Settings > Keymap > Right-click on 'Open Recent', no menu pops up to allow me to assign a hotkey.

I'm using Intellij 12.0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because `File/Open Recent` is not an action, but a "folder" for recent projects appearing in a submenu.

You can assign a shortcut to the `Reopen Recent Project` action which you can find under `Other` in the `Keymap` settings pane.